# Converter String para Double mantendo conteúdo

Tags: java, string, conversão-de-tipo, double

Preciso em Java converter uma `String` que possui um valor binário (Ex: "0111010") para um `double`. Testei:

```
String teste = "101010101";
double number = Double.parseDouble(teste);
System.out.println("The number is: " + number);
```

Porém a saída é um numero hexadecimal totalmente diferente. Preciso que a saída seja o mesmo conteúdo da `String`. O `double` pode até colocar ponto em algum lugar, sem problemas, mas precisa manter o mesmo binário e na mesma ordem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não consegui reproduzir o problema. Pra mim deu certo. Claro, apareceu em notação científica. Se o seu desejo é apresentar em notação de ponto flutuantes, aí precisa usar a função que permite formatar a apresentação:

```
System.out.printf("The number is: %f", number);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/bOh7BX). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/tvxmysvx-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Typing/FormatDouble.java).

[Documentação do formatador](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

Comment: Claro, detalhe importante que não me lembrei. É isso! Obrigado.

Comment: Eu não fiz qualquer tentativa de transformar a `String` em `double` porque aquele número seria inválido. Se fosse para um inteiro até daria e tem função pronta para isto. Também tem para `double`, mas o texto precisa estar em formato que possa ser convertido corretamente.